# How to create a data grid with sortable header and a scroll bar in GWT?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I want to create a data grid in GWT. It should have some features like,

- sortable headers
- automatic scroll bar
- custom styling for selected row in the grid.
- custom styling for selected cell in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Then simply create a [DataGrid](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html). It has automatic scrollbar, custom styles for selected rows and columns as well as functionality for adding sorting to headers.

For sorting please refer to [ListHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler.html)